# What are the IP adresses of DNS servers?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I've been wondering for a while, what are the IP addresses of DNS servers? Every computer on the internet must have an IP address. DNS servers are just computers on the internet. If a client computer wants to connect to a (say, the web server for Google's home page), then it must undergo the following process.

1. A client computer (192.168.0.108) sends a request to a DNS server (???) to resolve the domain name www.google.com through a home network device (76.67.253.228) via a network of routers.
2. The request then reaches the DNS server (???) who responds to the client computer with the IP address 172.217.165.4.
3. The client computer then requests the web server (172.217.165.4) for a specific web page.
4. The web server (172.217.165.4) then responds with a specific web page, and the request is complete!

My question is what is the IP address labeled ??? in the above process. Does your browser automatically know it?

Comment: The key concept you need to understand in the DNS to answer your question is the difference between recursive and authoritative nameservers. You are right nameservers are like any other hosts on the Internet, they have one or more IP addresses, and those IP are found exactly like any other, with the DNS. Of course there is some bootstrap case to know about, which are the root servers and how their IP addresses is embedded in all nameservers source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the IP address labeled ??? in the above process?

**it's the DNS servers, DNS servers are some IPs set on your system. the most famous one are Google DNS servers: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4. will explain more details later.**

Does your browser automatically know it?

**For some situations, yes. but sometimes, no.**

---

As you described, you have a computer, and you know you have an IP address(192.168.0.108) set on your computer. regarding the IP address, there are two ways to set it:

1. set manually. you need to fill out IP address, netmask, gateway IP, and DNS server(s).
2. set automatically. most of the computers will have them set automatically. that's the reason why even you don't know anything about computers, you still can use it to go shopping and watch movies after you opened an account from Xfinity and followed some very simple steps. it's because there is a DHCP server.

---

when your computer connected with an internet cable, or a WIFI. it'll try to find a DHCP server.

something like you walk into a classroom, and shout to everyone: any DHCP server here? (we call it broadcast) if there is, this guy (DHCP server) will give you:

1. one IP address, which is the one you mentioned 192.168.0.108.
2. netmask, usually is 255.255.255.0 if you're at home
3. gateway IP, usually is the 192.168.0.1, which is the first number of 192.168.0.x).
4. and also two DNS servers, maybe 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4, or some other.
   after that, your browser, Office and other apps will use these setting to get data from Internet.

---

this DHCP server will be installed in your router, or you call it home network device. when you get this device from your network providers, they must make sure everything is working good, especially the DHCP server and  DNS servers, because it's very hard to change it after they give it to customers.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are 2 steps here.

- Your client computer will know which DNS Server to ask. This is part of it's local configuration. It gets an IP Address, a default route, a network mask AND - the address of a DNS Server to ask. If your computer does not know it, something is **seriously** wrong in your computer network setup.
- Ultimately this DNS server (which likely is local or run by your provider) **either** knows another DNS Server to ask **or** - has a list of known **root servers**. Those are **known** and part of the configuration of a DNS Server. I.e. you install a DNS Server, it automatically will have a copy of the known list.

Read more at

https://securitytrails.com/blog/dns-root-servers